# Converting a RDD with an array into a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have an RDD that looks like the following. I'm trying to convert it to a dataframe of ['TS', 'val', 'Key'] in python(pyspark). Any help is appreciated as I'm pretty new.

```
root
 |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- key: long (nullable = true)

+--------------------+---+
|                 val|key|
+--------------------+---+
|[1.466095512E9, 6...|  0|
|[1.466097304E9, 6...|  1|
|[1.466099099E9, 6...|  2|
|[1.466100895E9, 7...|  3|
|[1.466102698E9, 7...|  4|
```

I tried this but I got an error on the `.toDF` line, with no explanation.

```
FN2 = FN.map(lambda x, y: (x[0], x[1], y))
Square = FN2.toDF(['TS','val','key']) #Converts to dataframe
Square.show()
```

Comment: If your RDD is created directed off of a csv file for example, you can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to directly change it to a dataframe.

Comment: What is `TS`? It is not in your sample.

Comment: TS is UnixTime. Its the first column, val is the 2nd column, key is the third column. Currently, TS and val are stored as an array

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function contains an error, try with

```
FN2 = FN.map(lambda (x, y): (x[0], x[1], y))
```

In general, each row is passed to map as a single argument, so the safest way is to map using someting like

```
FN2 = FN.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was an array inside an array

```
FN2 = FN.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]))
Square = FN2.toDF(['TS','val','key']) 
Square.show()
```